# Cannot start emulator on Android Studio 2.0 Preview b3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After updating both Android Studio to 2.0 Preview 3b & Android SDK Tools to 25rc1, Android studio would encounter an error when starting a Android 6.0 emulator with Google services:
[image]

The error seem to indicate that HAXM is of the wrong version (1.1.1 v.s. 6.0.1), however in Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tools the most up-to-date Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator version is installed (i.e. 6.0.1), so the error message doesn't seem to be correct.

Here's the emulator setting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the 6.0.1 installer downloaded is different from actually running the installer.

Go into your  folder, to `extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` and execute the `intelhaxm-android.exe` installer.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196864 I also have problems with the emulator can't start it :-(

Answer (score 1):

The UI under SDK Tools is a bit confusing. When it says 6.0.1 is installed, it's really saying that it downloaded the HAXM 6.0.1 installer. You still need to run the installer to install it.

Or, you can just download and install it manually from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/).